# MySQL XML obtain first child

Tags: mysql, xml

I have an XML format as below:

```
<a>
  <b>x</b>
  <b>y</b>
  <b>z</b>
  <c>something</c>
</a>
```

How can I use MySQL to get the 1st child of `<a>` that is a node `<b>`? I need MySQL syntax to get the first child of certain type

Comment: Have you looked at [XML Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/xml-functions.html#function_extractvalue)? What part are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [MySQL function `ExtractValue(field,xpath)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/xml-functions.html#function_extractvalue) to select the elements inside your XML.

With XPath you can select the first element with the predicate `[1]`. With your given XML inside a MySQL Table, use the following select to return i.e. the first element inside `<a>`:

```
select ExtractValue(content, '/a/*[1]') from YourTable;
```

This will return the value `x`. If you want to get the first `<b>` just use this select:

```
select ExtractValue(content, '/a/b[1]') from YourTable;
```